# vb.net receive json data in POST where key has forward slash

Tags: vb.net, rest, http-post

I have a restful web service that is receiving a POST with json data coming over.  Here is the json sample with the third key/pair having a forward slash in the key name.

```
{
    "_notes": "Test",
    "_received": true,
    "item/id": "8a69d38fba4c40d5a3d730807db87859"
}
```

Here is my Post method

```
Public Sub Post(value As Testing)
```

And here is the Testing Class definition

```
Public Class Testing
    Public _notes As String
    Public _received As Boolean
    Public item/ID As String
End Class
```

I get a compiler error since I can't have the forward slash in the variable name.  Is there a different way I'm supposed to be capturing the data on my side?  Unfortunately I can't control the key name in the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the .NET Web API framework's built-in de-serialization, you should spend some time learning about those serializers and how to control them.  [Here is a good introductory point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) in the documentation.

The built-in stuff uses JSON.NET, by default, for JSON serialization, which has [a number of attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) which allow you to control it.  The one you will be interested in for this problem is the [JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).  For instance:

```
Public Class Testing
    Public _notes As String
    Public _received As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("item/id")>
    Public ItemID As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling to find Documentation as everything seems to be about making the POST and not handling it.